# How do you draw an X in a 2d array? C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Assuming foo[10][10] is already full of ' ' here is my code so far:

```
for(int q = 0; q <10; q++)
{
foo[q][q] = 'x';
}
```

This draws a line from the top left to the bottom right, but I can not figure out how to draw a line from the bottom left to the top right without putting in another loop.
I know its simple, but I think I am missing an important bit of logic.

Can you make an X with only one loop, or am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int q = 0; q <10; q++)
{
    foo[q][q] = 'x';
    foo[q][10 - q - 1] = 'x';
}

10 - q - 1 = 9 - q
```

`9` is the max index of the array.

Comment: Dang, I knew it would be something really easy like that. Just could not get my finger on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done using a single loop with multiple variables.
As the value if i increases the value of j is decreasing. 
hence foo[j][i] will refer to

```
foo[9][0]   for the first iteration 
foo[8][1]   for the second iteration 
foo[7][2]   for the third iteration 
.....
till 
foo[0][9]   for the last iteration
```

this makes the loop put 'x' along the diagonal from the bottom left to top right as you asked.

```
for(int q = 0 ,int j=9 ; q <10; q++,j--)
{
foo[q][q] = 'x';
foo[j][q] = 'x';
}
```